# Trigger for updating description field Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I am facing problem while updating description field in the table.
If description is more than 4000 character I have to update "XYZ" table with 4000 characters only and truncate rest of the characters. Can anyone help me out writing trigger to do so...

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what you are attempting to do? I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Do we really need a trigger here? All that is needed is a substring of 4000 characters of the input value. It is better to apply SUBSTR on the input value before INSERT. That should avoid the need for the trigger and the subsequent maintenance issues altogether. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger looks like below: This will truncate the the characters when inserted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_xyz
before insert on xyz for each row    
Begin

:new.description := substr(:new.description,1,4000)  ; 

end;
/
```